# Python Azure functions queue binding

Tags: python, azure, azure-webjobssdk

How do I use a queue output binding in a python azure function. Here is the binding in my function.json

```
{
  "type": "queueTrigger",
  "name": "myQueue", 
  "direction": "out",
  "queueName": "qname",
  "connection": "CONNECTION"
}
```

My code ends with this

```
open(os.environ[myQueue], ‘wb’) as q:
    q.write(‘message’)
```

I just get an error to do with being unable to open QueueAttribute for writing. Anyone had experience with this because there is no documentation at all.

Comment: Hi, any progress now?

Answer (score 1):

I tried to use queue storage output binding in a python azure function and it works well for me .I did not reproduce your issue.

You could refer to the steps I worked.

Step 1: Create HttpTrigger for Python.

[image]

Step 2: Configure queue storage output binding as below.

[image]

Step 3: Check run.py code and function.json

**run.py**

```
import os
import json

postreqdata = json.loads(open(os.environ['req']).read())
response = open(os.environ['res'], 'w')
response.write("hello world from "+postreqdata['name'])
response.close()
```

**function.json**

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "function",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "methods": [
        "post"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "queue",
      "name": "res",
      "queueName": "outqueue",
      "connection": "jaygong_STORAGE",
      "direction": "out"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false
}
```

Step 4 ：Run the function and check storage queue message.

[image]

You could also refer to the [official tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-triggers-bindings) and [Queue Storage Output Binding Configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-queue).

Hope it helps you.